# Can the devexpress Gridview Control be used completely in unbound mode?

Tags: devexpress, aspxgridview

I want to use the Aspx gridview with out connect it to datasource

Comment: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/CQ61311

Answer (score 0):

**From:** [Add new unbound row in bound AspxGridView](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q206267)

> The ASPxGridView can't display unbound rows. As a possible solution,
>   create an intermediate in-memory datasource (e.g. DataTable), copy
>   rows from your read-only datasource into it, and bind it to the grid.
>   Then, you'll be able to programmatically add new rows to this
>   datasource.

You can manage in memory DataSet(other datasource types), to populate data in the grid. There are lots of DevExpress threads about such type of requirements. I suggest you to go through them and implement in the way that you like to prefer.

[ASPxGridView - How to manipulate data without data source](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q290629)
[aspxgridview without datasources](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q246903)
[Add new unbound row in bound AspxGridView](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q206267)